# Changing the dimension of an arrow

Tags: spacing, tikz-cd

I'm drawing a commutative diagram using the package `tikzd`. The problem is that the lenght of the arrows is too much. So I'm tring to find a way to reduce it. I'm using the command `\arrow` to draw the line. Is there an option in this code to do it?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? It's easier and faster for us to fix existing code than writing it from scratch. Don't forget to make it short and compilable.

Comment: `column sep=small`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing of the grid (and hence the length of the arrow) using the parameters `column sep`, `row sep`, or just `sep` which comprises both.  Valid values are:

- `tiny` (corresponds 0.6 em)
- `small` (corresponds 1.2 em)
- `scriptsize` (corresponds 1.8 em)
- `normal` (corresponds 2.4 em)
- `large` (corresponds 3.6 em)
- `huge` (corresponds 4.8 em)